# Connecting Altera de2 to a sensor via UART

Tags: analog, rs232, verilog, proximity-sensor

Is Nios II required when implementing UART core using the SOPC? (or a default Nios is included) I tried writing my own module for the uart connection but it didn't work out. I need a method to  connect a sensor to the de2, any method is fine. If you guys could give a clear method about how can this be implemented

[This link](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~sedwards/classes/2009/4840/designs/RC.pdf) gives an idea what could be done but its not that clear

I need a idea on how to go about it. With so many manuals and softwares available for the Altera..

Comment: possible duplicate of [De2 Board reading sensor reading](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/22180/de2-board-reading-sensor-reading)

Comment: No.  A UART is basically a state machine.  Though if your data to be transmitted or received gets more complicated than you want to handle in a state machine, you might start to consider some sort of soft processor core.  That said, while UARTs are very doable, SPI-type interfaces are simpler to implement, so if not dictated by what is on the other end, you might consider that.

Answer (score 1):

No, a NIOS II is not actually required when using IP components from QSys (the replacement for SoPC Builder), since you may always **export** the Avalon-MM bus which typically connects to the NIOS II. This breaks out a port which corresponds to the Avalon-MM bus from your QSys HDL module, which you can then directly drive with a state machine in your FPGA that serves as the Avalon-MM master in lieu of the Nios II. You will have to design your state machine to be a Avalon-MM master, refer to the document [Avalon Interface Specification](https://www.altera.com/content/dam/altera-www/global/en_US/pdfs/literature/manual/mnl_avalon_spec.pdf) for relevant signals and timing diagrams.

With that being said, it may be excessive to implement an entire Avalon-MM interface for a UART. In this case, you should look into the many available open-source UART interfaces (assuming this is not for a class project where you have to implement it yourself). An example is a [simple UART](http://opencores.org/project,mmuart) found on OpenCores.

Answer (score 0):

The following links MAY be of use to you.
 Zero guarantees.

[DE2 Hyerterminal wannabe](http://www.alteraforum.com/forum/showthread.php?t=732)

[RS232 from scales wannabe](http://www.alteraforum.com/forum/showthread.php?s=b8caef49326bba44232075d1852e87ad&t=5430)

[UART / DE2 with links elsewhere](http://www-ug.eecg.utoronto.ca/desl/nios_devices/dev_rs232uart.html)

[This looks useful](http://www-ug.eecg.utoronto.ca/desl/nios_devices/datasheets/Altera%20RS-232.pdf) Altera UART core overview. Chapter 8 in vaguely specified manual.

Do you have / are you using SOPC builder?
 It SOUNDs to do what you want

- The universal asynchronous receiver/transmitter core with Avalon®
  interface (UART core) implements a method to communicate serial 
  character streams between an embedded system on an Altera®
  FPGA and 
  an external device. The core implements the RS-232 protocol timing, and 
  provides adjustable baud rate, parity, stop and data bits, and optional 
  RTS/CTS flow control signals. The feature set is configurable, allowing 
  designers to implement just the necessary functionality for a given 
  system.

  The core provides a simple register-mapped Avalon Memory-Mapped 
  (Avalon-MM) slave interface that allows Avalon-MM master peripherals 
  (such as a Nios®
  II processor) to communicate with the core simply by 
  reading and writing control and data registers.

  The UART core is SOPC Builder-ready and integrates easily into any 
  SOPC Builder-generated system. This chapter contains the following 
  sections:
  ■ “Functional Description” on page 8–2
  ■ “Device and Tools Support” on page 8–4
  ■ “Instantiating the Core in SOPC Builder” on page 8–4
  ■ “Hardware Simulation Considerations” on page 8–9
  ■ “Software Programming Model” on page 8–9

One level up [above chapter plus many other modules](http://www-ug.eecg.utoronto.ca/desl/nios_devices/datasheets/)

[Using the DE2 JTAG UART](http://www-ug.eecg.toronto.edu/desl/manuals/DE2_Media_Computer.pdf) about page 9 on.