# LV EZ1 - TX output

Tags: rs232, proximity-sensor

This is a continuation from this question: [De2 Board reading sensor reading](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/22180/de2-board-reading-sensor-reading).

Will this be the output from the sensor ... 1(idle)0(start)1010010(82 - R in binary)1(stop-bit) 0(start)#distance in binary# 1(stopbit)1(idle)0(start)#distance in binary# 1(stopbit)

So my main question is the R stated in the image, is that only the first time for handshake and then distances?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are misreading what it says.

Set UART in receiver to 9600 baud one stop bit, no parity.
Read what it says in page you quote re levels.

Then ...

When *BW is open or low, the board sends strings of 5 ASCII characters on the TX pin.

From what it says I ASSUME that it then pauses and then repeats.
 If you have a board it would very very very very easy to look at the TX pin and see.

The 5 character ASCII string is equal to.

ASCII "R"  = $52
 Digit1
 Digit2
 Digit3
 ASCII Carriage return = $0d= 13_decimal

Digit1 Digit2 Digit 3 gives3 ASCII coded digits 0-9 to give values 000 to 255 max. Order MAY be reversed (LSD first).

Sending this to a PC using a  terminal program would display for eg a ramp that happened to ramp at one count per string.

000
 001
 002
 003